# Regex: select first and last occurence of [] in a String

Tags: java, json, regex, geojson

I'm trying automate changing coordinates in a GeoJSON message:

```
{
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {},
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "LineString",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                4.399842023849487,
                51.97148460936231
            ],
            [
                4.386194944381714,
                52.003202463721045
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

To do this, i'm looking for a way to select the first coordinate pair (          4.399842023849487,51.97148460936231) and last ( 4.386194944381714,52.003202463721045. In this case, there are only 2 pairs, but regex should look for last pair.).
Subsequently, these 2 selected Strings will be replaced by 2 coordinates that i've already extracted from another source.

What is the most sturdy/robust way to do this? Is regex the way to go?

EDIT:

Solved it with the org.json parser.

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputdata);
        JSONArray coordinateArr = obj.getJSONArray("coordinates");

        String firstOldCoordinate = coordinateArr.get(0).toString();
        String lastOldCoordinate = coordinateArr.get(1).toString();

        String newJSON = inputdata.replace(firstOldCoordinate, firstNewCoordinate).replace(lastOldCoordinate, lastNewCoordinate);
```

Comment: using a json parser should help u a great deal.

Comment: why don't you use json parser? Json parser is more the way to go.

Comment: DON'T! Use a parser instead.

Comment: *"What is the most sturdy/robust way to do this?"* Use a JSON parser, make your change in the resulting object's arrays, then use a JSON serializer. *"Is regex the way to go?"* No.

Comment: use json parser [gson](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/gson-example-read-and-write-json.html)  or [jackson](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/) and get json array of coordinates then fetch arr[0]/arr.get(0) and arr[arr.size()-1]/arr.get(arr.size()-1) as required jsonNodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not consider regex as a neat and efficient solution to do all this. Instead using jQuery.parseJSON() is the best way. Check out the solution below. Here is the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/hacker1211/ewoma0tc/

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"type": "Feature","properties": {},"geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": [[4.399842023849487,51.97148460936231],[4.386194944381714,52.003202463721045]]}}' );
obj.geometry.coordinates[0]=[7.399842023849487,60.97148460936231]; //your custom coordinates
obj.geometry.coordinates[obj.geometry.coordinates.length-1]=[7.399842023849487,60.97148460936231];//your custom coordinates
alert( obj.geometry.coordinates[0]);
alert( obj.geometry.coordinates[obj.geometry.coordinates.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq) the task can be accomplished using the following jq filter:

```
.geometry.coordinates[0] = ["one", "two"]
| .geometry.coordinates[-1] = ["three", "four"]
```

where you'd replace the strings with the appropriate values.

Assuming the input is in a file named geojson.json and that the above two lines are in a file name geojson.jq, here is a transcript showing the output:

```
$ jq -f geojson.jq geojson.json
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        "one",
        "two" 
      ],
      [
        "three",
        "four"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

The above assumes jq version 1.5 (the current release); with jq 1.4, the program would be these three lines:

```
(.geometry.coordinates|length -1 ) as $last
| .geometry.coordinates[0] = ["one", "two"]
| .geometry.coordinates[$last] = ["three", "four"]
```

The program can also easily be parameterized.